# Convert String to unicode from ansi/hexadecimal string

Tags: java, string, unicode, urlencode

I have a problem about string converter

I read the content from url

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&hl=us&ds=yt&q=spinner

and the result IN CONSOLE is

["spinner",["spinner","spinner tricks","spinner fidget","spinner vietnam","spinner skill","spinner toy","spinner fidget toy","spinner vn","spinner hand","spinner vi\u1EC7t nam"]]

it contains string "spinner vi\u1EC7t nam", but when read it BY OS, i see "việt nam"

The question is how i can read content of api to see "việt nam" as result.

Below is my raw code

```

```
    URL url = new URL("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&hl=us&ds=yt&q=spinner");
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    InputStreamReader reader      = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    reader.close();
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern UNICODE = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})");

static String decodeUnicodeEscape(String s) {
    Matcher m = UNICODE.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(sb,
            String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16)));
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(decodeUnicodeEscape(" vi\\u1EC7t nam"));
```

result

```
 việt nam
```